# Issue organizing my files with abstract classes and methods

Tags: php, laravel, abstract-class

I am working in a plugin that generate competitions trees.

So, I have mainly 2 types of competitions, `SingleElimination`, and `Playoff`

Inside SingleElimination, I have 2 cases, `SingleEliminationWithPreliminaryRound`,`SingleEliminationWithoutPreliminaryRound`,

for each competition type, I have 2 kind of players, teams, and competitors, basically, team is a collection of competitors.

So, I tried to organize my code this way:

```
-- TreeGen : (Abstract) All the common code, and the entry point

---- PlayOffTreeGen (Abstract extends TreeGen)

------ PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen (extends PlayOffTreeGen)

------ PlayOffTeamTreeGen (extends PlayOffTreeGen)

---- SingleEliminationTreeGen (Abstract extends TreeGen)

------ SingleEliminationTeamTreeGen (extends SingleEliminationTreeGen)

------ SingleEliminationCompetitorTreeGen (extends SingleEliminationTreeGen)
```

So, this organization works great, I avoid a lot of conditionals, and get lower complexity in overall, but now, I have methods that are duplicated in both `SingleEliminationCompetitorTreeGen` and `PlayOffCompetitorTreeGen` for instance.

So, I feel like it is the limit of this kind of architecture, but have no idea how should I make it evolve.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a trait? As an example, I have a form generation library, which uses DOMDocuments to generate the HTML (https://github.com/delboy1978uk/form).

Regardless of the form element, all these HTML entities can have Attributes set, so I ended up with duplicate code. I solved it by creating `HasAttributeTrait`:

```
namespace Del\Form\Traits;

trait HasAttributesTrait
{
    /** @var array $attributes */
    private $attributes = [];
    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        return isset($this->attributes[$key]) ? $this->attributes[$key] : null;
    }
    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }
}
```

Then, in any class that used to have private $attributes and getters and setters, now just say:

```
use Del\Form\Traits\HasAttributeTrait;

class Whatever
{
     use HasAtttributesTrait;

    // other code here
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
$something = new Whatever();
$something->setAttribute('href', $url);
```

Note that traits only work from PHP 5.4+, but of course, you are up to date, right? ;-)